# What's the best way to create a shopping cart in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart, laravel-8

What's the best way to create a shopping cart in laravel 8?

There are many sources in github but they don't work correctly for laravel 8.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/releases/tag/4.2.0 works in Laravel 8. I'm creating a project using it right now.

Comment: I'm having lots of problems using it. I'm trying to clear the items and after clearing and removing the command, the products show up again.

Comment: Admittedly this is the first time I'm using this particular package, just for a change to see what it's like, but haven't found any issues thus far. You could try https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart/releases/tag/2.9, which I've used a lot in the past.

Comment: I think I made it work now, I don't relaly know whast's was wrong. Thanks

Comment: How can I make it so doesn't need to reload to add in cart?

Comment: You could use Laravel Livewire, then create a component/method and call it from your add to cart form. You could use standard JS or a JS library to create an ajax request. There are many options.